# Wordpress "insert-php": php code from file not executing

Tags: php, wordpress, require, require-once

I have a WP site, I installed Insert-PHP plugin. (I am really new to WP).
On a new page I wrote in the "text" tab:

```
[insert_php]
require_once(realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]) ."/firstfolder/nextfolder/test-1.php");
[/insert_php]
```

Then, in `"/firstfolder/nextfolder/test-1_1.php"` I have:

```
 <?php
    print 'something';
    ?>
```

At first I had problems w/ `require_once` because the path wasn't good. Then I managed and the page was working fine, displaying the word "something" as content.

A few hours later it's not working anymore. If I write PHP code between `[insert_php]` tags it's doing fine, but if I do the same thing in "test-1.php" nothing happens. No errors or warnings, nothing, just a blank page.

I even tried to write code to force an error and nothing happened. I cleared the cache, I tried created another file w/ that code ... nothing. I intentionally misspelled the path in `require_once` and that did produce an error.

The only thing happened between the time the code was executing and now is that I installed a "Yoast SEO" plugin.

What could have possibly happen? :(

Answer (score 0):

So, thank you very much for support :| that was great.

I must say that I did not solve the mystery. Maybe I did something wrong somewhere or there is an issue with the "Insert PHP" plugin.

I'll write here what solution I came up with, maybe someone in the future will find a similar problem.
I installed another plugin called "Include Me". I used that to enter the path to the needed php file and after that everything was fine.